# ListView of radio buttons property set doesn't hit

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image]

this is the data template using my ViewModel

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MultipleKeysSectionViewModel}" >
    <views:TabListItemUserControl Text="{Binding Header}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

here is my list of radio buttons

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs.Keys}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsMultiple, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}} SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParameterName}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,5,0" GroupName="FilterParameters"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

here is my property

```
private string _selectedParameterName;
public string SelectedParameterName
{
   get { return _selectedParameterName; }
   set
    {
       _selectedParameterName = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedParameterName);
    }
}
```

this is my the collection I bind the ListView into

```
public Dictionary<string, RegisterListViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
```

however when I clicked the radio button it doesn't go to Set of the SelectedParameterName property

only when i hit the "box" containing the name of the radio button Set is executed.

Has anyone come across this issue before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `IsChecked` property of the `RadioButton` is not bound to anything, therefore clicking on the `RadioButton` will do nothing.

Change your RadioButton to this:

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,5,0"
             IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
```

Comment: ok how do implement the IsSelected property in runtime for the data template?

Comment: @Androidy I don't understand your question. have you tried my code?

Comment: I get the same behavior, I guess that is because i don't have IsSelected property. what i don't understand is how each button has it's own IsSelected property. I have added the collection i'm using

Comment: @Androidy the `IsSelected` property belongs to the `ListViewItem`s, not to the ViewModel. I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: in the image up, i have two radio button created in run-time using Dictionary<string, RegisterListViewModel> Tabs; I am able to display them and now i want to know which radio button the user has chosen. for that i created a property SelectedParameterName, i want to set it according to the chosen radio button

Comment: I thought of maybe holding a Dictionary of <string, bool> so each radio button will have it's own boolean for is checked.

Comment: ok so your code works the only problem i had is the Margin for some reason i was able to click on the sides of it! OMG WPF

Comment: @HighCore: How do I get the radio button checked as well along with the code above?

Comment: @asterveigas you don't "get the radiobutton checked" because the radiobutton just reflects the selection state from the `ListViewItem.IsSelected` property, which also depends from the `ListView.SelectedItem` property. Just put a binding `ListView SelectedItem={Binding Something}` and read that from the ViewModel.

Comment: @HighCore: I get to know which Item is selected in my ViewModel but in the UI, the radio button is never checked. Can I achieve that as well?

Comment: @AsterVeigas how are you setting the selected item? are you raising NotifyPropertyChanged too?

Comment: @HighCore I have bound the Selected Index and ItemsSource. So I get to know which item is selected in my view model. But the problem is since I bound the radiobutton ischecked event to Listview's isSelected,I'm not able to check the radio button at all.

Comment: @asterveigas instead of selected `Index`, use `SelectedItem`. and make sure you `NotifyPropertyChange()` when setting the ViewModel property. WPF will automatically listen to that event and update the UI.